# Example from Rust in Action does not work

Tags: rust

I am following the textbook Rust in Action and trying to write the example on page 71:
When I try to define an args like:

```
let args = App::new("chapter1")
    .about("Searches for patterns!").arg(Arg::with_name("pattern"))
        .help("The pattern to look for!")
        .takes_value(true)
    .required(true).get_matches();
```

I get an error,

```
no method named `takes_value` found for struct `App` in the current scope
items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scoperustcE0599
any_arg.rs(37, 8): the method is available for `App<'_, '_>` here
main.rs(1, 1): the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:: `use clap::args::any_arg::AnyArg;
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Because it seems to work in the textbook?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? (for example: Where's the `App` item's struct, implementations, etc.?) What are your expectations? See [ask].

Comment: App is an external library used by the rust in action text book, my expectation is that the code compiles. Which it does not.

Comment: Author here - sorry that this has been a problem for you. A syntax error like that should not have ended up in the example. I am glad to see that a solution has been listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try instead (sorry, didn't test it):

```
let args = App::new("chapter1")
    .about("Searches for patterns!").arg(Arg::with_name("pattern")
        .help("The pattern to look for!")
        .takes_value(true))
    .required(true).get_matches();
```

or

```
let args = App::new("chapter1")
    .about("Searches for patterns!").arg(Arg::with_name("pattern")
        .help("The pattern to look for!")
        .takes_value(true)
        .required(true))
    .get_matches();
```

`takes_value()` in clap (version 3.*) is a method from the struct `Arg`, not `App`. The parentheses you show imply that it was referring to the struct `App`.